# Does sprigs in Aerospike reduces memory footprint of primary index compared to previous hybrid model?

Tags: database, caching, nosql, aerospike

I was going through the documentation of the new Aerospike release and found something called "sprigs", dividing the hash table into multiple small red-black trees for performance improvement. How does it reduce memory usage, what metadata does it store in memory and how it's different from hybrid model?

Any pointer to right documentation or explanation would help a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For large datasets, it can help with performance (the more sprigs, the shallower the tree to get to the entry, therefore the faster to get to it). It is particularly important for All Flash config. This is not different than the 'hybrid model' it is just an implementation detail of it... you always have sprigs, no matter what, you simply can configure their number.

**Memory usage**: [partition-tree-sprigs](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/index.html?show-removed=1#partition-tree-sprigs) config entry has details in the (Show more information).

The [FAQ - What are Sprigs](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-what-are-sprigs/4936) article has some details as well:

---

The namespace memory overhead per-node can be determined like this:

- A fixed base size of 64K.
- 8M times the replication factor for partition-tree-locks, divided by the number of nodes.
- 8B per partition-tree-sprigs times the replication factor, divided by the number of nodes.
- The Enterprise Edition requires an additional 5B per partition-tree-sprigs times the replication factor, divided by the number of nodes.